# Hike in meta space and classes loaded

Tags: java, memory, jvm, out-of-memory, heap-memory

Facing an issue after upgrading the application to Java 8.

Observation based on APM graphs :

Sudden jump in  classes loaded from 40K to 120K and simultaneously metaspace hiking from  20Mb to 256Mb( was max defined now removed it).

Error : *`java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace`*

GC data : `*[Full GC (Last ditch collection) [PSYoungGen: 0K->0K(1394688K)] [ParOldGen: 68568K->68568K(2796544K)] 68568K->68568K(4191232K), [Metaspace: 251049K->251049K(1239040K)], 0.2309780 secs] [Times: user=0.32 sys=0.00, real=0.23 secs]*`

•   120k class files are getting loaded into metaspace memory and not getting unloaded.

Relevant JVM parameters :

```
    -Xms256M \
   -Xmx4g \
   -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError \
   -XX:+PrintGCDetails \
   -XX:+TraceClassUnloading \
   -XX:+TraceClassLoading \
   -XX:HeapDumpPath=/somepath \
   -XX:MetaspaceSize=64m \
```

I have recently added TraceClassUnloading and TraceClassLoading  to get the root cause.

Any other solution would be really helpful, let me know if any more info is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Permanent fix : Updating the version of JAXB-IMPL.

Add the VM parameter for temporary resolution :

`Dcom.sun.xml.bind.v2.bytecode.ClassTailor.noOptimize=true`

Answer (score 0):

you can use following command to find class loaded in Metaspace

`jcmd PID GC.class_stats`

The latter requires -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions